# Filter string with non-English character in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have this list for example

`items = ['www1bmobạnk.com', 'наш-переславль.рф', 'вольттек.рф', '別邸福の花浜松町店.com', 'благовест.рус', 'թարմլուր.հայ', '피시방.com', 'ått.com', '沃華科技.com', 'впамяти.рф', 'андрейбабкин.рф', '꽃셰프가.com', 'фортуна36.рф', 'わかば.com', 'тесты-на-коронавирус.рф', '第一個夏天.com', 'bëstchange.net', 'normaldomain.com']`

I'm using `re.match` to filter them out

```
for item in items:
    if re.match('[a-z0-9]', item):
        print("It's English! " + item)
    else:
        print("It's not! " + item)
```

The issue is `bëstchange.net` and `www1bmobạnk.com` didn't get filtered. I added `[^ë]` and it worked for `bëstchange.net`, but `[^ạ]` didn't work for `www1bmobạnk.com`. I also try Unicode `[\u0061-\u007A]`, but it's pretty much the same thing.

Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a string contains a letter that is not an ASCII letter:

```py
import re
items = ['www1bmobạnk.com', 'наш-переславль.рф', 'вольттек.рф', '別邸福の花浜松町店.com', 'благовест.рус', 'թարմլուր.հայ', '피시방.com', 'ått.com', '沃華科技.com', 'впамяти.рф', 'андрейбабкин.рф', '꽃셰프가.com', 'фортуна36.рф', 'わかば.com', 'тесты-на-коронавирус.рф', '第一個夏天.com', 'bëstchange.net', 'normaldomain.com']
for item in items:
    if not re.search(r'(?![a-zA-Z])[^\W\d_]', item):
        print(f"It's English! {item}")
    else:
        print(f"It's not! {item}")
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6uqT0b). Only `normaldomain.com` passes the test now.

The `(?![a-zA-Z])[^\W\d_]` pattern matches any Unicode letter (with `[^\W\d_]`) but the `(?![a-zA-Z])` negative lookahead "tempers", restricts this pattern so that it could not match an ASCII letter.

Comment: Thank you! I found another one that got away 'p̲o̲f̲.cf'. Do you have another suggestion? :(

Comment: @Nathan Do you want to detect if a string contains a diacritic mark? Then you need a solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61601850/3832970). See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/KlpUWJ).